# VMware null modem serial cable between virtual machines

Tags: windows, linux, vmware, virtualization, null-modem

Right now I am using some software to emulate a null modem serial cable on my Windows computer connected to itself. For development purposes I need to have a null modem connection to a linux computer from a windows host. Is there any method of doing this virtually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the closest thing to an answer is to use [com2tcp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/com0com/), which allows you to redirect a serial port to a telnet server. Its not entirely what I was aiming for but should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use remserial to have multiple linux vm's share a remote serial connection, but it didn't work. I believe my problem was due to my application not playing well with the tty designations remserial uses. You may have better luck with it.

[Here](http://lpccomp.bc.ca/remserial/) is the remserial website.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_port_redirector) is the wikipedia page where I learned about it (see Open Source Solutions section).

Answer (score 0):

I thing also `netcat` can be used for this see e.g. following [link](http://blog.philippklaus.de/2011/08/make-rs232-serial-devices-accessible-via-ethernet/#comment-12420)